# mysql select SET separator

Tags: mysql, types

I have a table with a set type.

this fields is a color labels:

```
set('Red', 'Blue', 'Green')
```

each record can have multiple colors like:

> red and blue

now when i select i get:

> Red,Blue,Green

is it possible to change this to:

> Blue - Green - Red

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select substr(concat(
    if(color='Blue', ' - Blue', ''),
    if(color='Green',' - Green', ''),
    if(color='Red',' - Red','')
), 3) as customfield
```

Comment: so if i had more colors, i will have to change my query each time?